# Multiple database contexts in our integration test seems to fail intermittently and adding ToList() doesn't fix it

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am having intermittent problems with a colleagues' integration test which is running as a unit test.  Sometimes it works on my machine and sometimes it does not although when it stops working, it seems to stay 'stuck' not working for a while.  I haven't figured out how I get it to work again either.

When I try to debug it the error is in the second DBContext (ctx1) - it errors saying:

1. Message=The 'UpdatedOn' property on 'MyCollection' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'. 
   Source=EntityFramework
2. collection.Local has only one item in it - which is the new item added in the previous context.
3. collection.ResultsView - when i try to enumerate the results of collection there is another error: 
   "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

MyDBContext is based ultimately on EF6 DbContext.

```
        public void CanAddItem()
        {
            using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                                                            new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0),
                                                            TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                int initialCount;
                // Arrange
                using (IMyDBContext ctx = new MyDBContext(new AppConfigReader()))
                {
                    var matched = ctx.MyCollection;

                    initialCount = matched.Count();

                    var item = new MyItem
                    {
                        UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                    };

                    // Act
                    ctx.MyCollection.Add(item);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }

                //Assert
                using (IMyDBContext ctx1 = new MyDBContext(new AppConfigReader()))
                {
                    var collection = ctx1.MyCollection;

                    collection.Should().HaveCount(initialCount + 1);
                }
            }
```

I have tried adding `.ToList()` to make `var collection = ctx1.MyCollection.ToList()` but it just moves the error into that line of code.

I think his rationale in using two contexts is to prove that the value is always written to the database and doesn't get stuck in the DbContext.  It always runs on his machine.

I need to make it work so it works all the time.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the world has to see my silly mistakes.  I finally ran the SQL query that led me to realize that the entity definition was not the same as the database definition and that there happened to be, in my database, from time to time, values where UpdatedOn WAS NULL!

Lessons learned.

Comment: If it is fixed, could you please accept your own answer :)

Comment: It says i have to wait 2 days :(